# ModX Revolution: method get pass encoded character

Tags: search, methods, get, code-snippets, modx

I am using SimpleSearch snippet in Modx Revolution CMS for searching webpage content.
Using form like this:

```
<form class="sisea-search-form" action="[[~[[+landing]]]]" method=get>
<input type="text" name="hledej" id="hledej" value="[[+searchValue:default=`Hledej...`]]" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Hledej...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Hledej...';}" />
```

Searching on webpage works, except for strings with specials characters like "ěščřžýáá" (different language). Problem is that method get encode pass this character in url like this:
../search-result.html?search=str%25C3%25A1nce&id=13
and find 0 results....
if the search string in url is not encoded (tried to rewrite it manually), it returns some results...
I also tried to use method post, but id doesnt work at all...
Any idea?

Comment: As far as I know, that is the proper way to transport special characters, to make sure they don't accidentally escape or alter content. Your problem is more likely that your charset is one type coming from the webpage and another in the database, or it could even be a different charset from page to page. This really shouldn't happen in ModX, but it can on occasion. Try making a chunk with a snippet in it, that outputs the $_GET parameters, to see what is actually received by php in the other end.

Comment: There might be a problem with mysql encoding, there is mix of utf8_general and utf8_czech

Comment: As long as they are both UTF-8 it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Is it possible to be a hosting problem?

Comment: So is there any solution (or way to solve) to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works correctly on different hosting, so problem is probably somewhere else. 
I am closing this topic.